# How do Jersey endpoints call each other?

Tags: java, angular, maven, escaping, guacamole

I investigate source code code of [guacamole-client](https://github.com/apache/guacamole-client):

I try to understand how `/api/session/data/postgresql/activeConnections`

I was able to run the application, call the endpoint and I debug it.

I was able to put breakpoint [here](https://github.com/apache/guacamole-client/blob/06374de1a5df4823de8ddfb569facd0002265efb/guacamole/src/main/java/org/apache/guacamole/rest/session/UserContextResource.java#L169):

```
@Path("activeConnections")
public DirectoryResource<ActiveConnection, APIActiveConnection>
    getActiveConnectionDirectoryResource() throws GuacamoleException {
    return activeConnectionDirectoryResourceFactory.create(authenticatedUser,
            userContext, userContext.getActiveConnectionDirectory());
}
```

and I stoped here.

Also I see that after that method call [another method](https://github.com/apache/guacamole-client/blob/06374de1a5df4823de8ddfb569facd0002265efb/guacamole/src/main/java/org/apache/guacamole/rest/directory/DirectoryResource.java#L399) is called to prepare response:

```
@GET
public Map<String, ExternalType> getObjects(
        @QueryParam("permission") List<ObjectPermission.Type> permissions)
        throws GuacamoleException {

    // An admin user has access to all objects
    Permissions effective = userContext.self().getEffectivePermissions();
    SystemPermissionSet systemPermissions = effective.getSystemPermissions();
    boolean isAdmin = systemPermissions.hasPermission(SystemPermission.Type.ADMINISTER);

    // Filter objects, if requested
    Collection<String> identifiers = directory.getIdentifiers();
    if (!isAdmin && permissions != null && !permissions.isEmpty()) {
        ObjectPermissionSet objectPermissions = getObjectPermissions(effective);
        identifiers = objectPermissions.getAccessibleObjects(permissions, identifiers);
    }

    // Translate each retrieved object into the corresponding external object
    Map<String, ExternalType> apiObjects = new HashMap<String, ExternalType>();
    for (InternalType object : directory.getAll(identifiers))
        apiObjects.put(object.getIdentifier(), translator.toExternalObject(object));

    return apiObjects;

}
```

But I don't see relation of those method in stacktrace.

Could anyone explain connection/relation/dependency between of those methods ?

Comment: Person who voted for the close because of lack of clarity. Please provide clarity what is unclear for you ? All steps to reproduce are provided. I have no idea what the additiona information you need ?